# Extract data from JSON API

Tags: c#, json

I need to modify a software.
I need to extract the "price" data from this, how can i do?

```
{
  "result": {
    "stats": [
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "1.8266",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 0,
        "speed": "14266.85620849"
      },
      {
        "price": "0.081",
        "profitability_btc": "0",
        "profitability_above_btc": "0",
        "algo": 1,
        "speed": "385908261.68241924"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 2,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0298",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 3,
        "speed": "595530.02421524"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0003",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 4,
        "speed": "2611.90080988"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.1404",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 5,
        "speed": "2260.49880031"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0003",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 6,
        "speed": "1050.4786522"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0031",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 7,
        "speed": "2467.60173312"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.1354",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 8,
        "speed": "42.42055349"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0001",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 9,
        "speed": "0.05507848"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 10,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.1721",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 11,
        "speed": "1676.32988734"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.209",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 12,
        "speed": "29233.19588795"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 13,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "3.72",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 14,
        "speed": "4429.92289544"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 15,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0057",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 16,
        "speed": "1374.37104"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 17,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 18,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0001",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 19,
        "speed": "0.00016779"
      },
      {
        "price": "0.0059",
        "algo": 20,
        "speed": "8824.36047254",
        "profitability_eth": "0",
        "profitability_above_eth": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0187",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 21,
        "speed": "370612.8438268"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.1729",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 22,
        "speed": "0.1064621"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0612",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 23,
        "speed": "36146.26380671"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.3499",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 24,
        "speed": "0.10152039"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.05",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 25,
        "speed": "26332.59479137"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0054",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 26,
        "speed": "3.70231186"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0049",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 27,
        "speed": "7123.4766245"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 28,
        "speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "profitability_above_ltc": "0",
        "price": "0.0043",
        "profitability_ltc": "0",
        "algo": 29,
        "speed": "16.33657586"
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": "stats.global.current"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: What is the existing code? What have you attempted?

Comment: First, you need to try

Answer (score 1):

Use Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package).

```
public class Stat
{
    public string profitability_above_ltc { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string profitability_ltc { get; set; }
    public int algo { get; set; }
    public string speed { get; set; }
    public string profitability_btc { get; set; }
    public string profitability_above_btc { get; set; }
    public string profitability_eth { get; set; }
    public string profitability_above_eth { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
}

var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");

RootObject deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

//deserializedProduct.Result[i].price  <-- this is what you want.
```

Comment: And where i put the http url from where i get the json data?

Comment: Ok, so the code is this:
public class HandlerClass
{
    public class Stat    {..}
    public class Result    {..}
    public class RootObject {..}
       public static void HandleOrder(ref Order OrderStats, ref double MaxPrice, ref double NewLimit)
       { var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
        if (json == null) return;
 RootObject deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        double nprice = deserializedProduct.Result[20].price;
MaxPrice = nprice;
}} 
But i get an error on the definiction of Result in HandlerClass.RootObject

Answer (score 0):

Use Json.Net. Write a class that repsresents a model and use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

If needed use inheritance and composition to build powerful model if needed.

there are also other libraries depending on what you want achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Install Newtonsoft json nuget package to you project.
   (https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)
2. Convert JSON response (string) to relative classes (http://json2csharp.com/ )

   public class Stat
   {
       public string profitability_above_ltc { get; set; }
       public string price { get; set; }
       public string profitability_ltc { get; set; }
       public int algo { get; set; }
       public string speed { get; set; }
       public string profitability_btc { get; set; }
       public string profitability_above_btc { get; set; }
       public string profitability_eth { get; set; }
       public string profitability_above_eth { get; set; }
   }

   public class Result
   {
       public List stats { get; set; }
   }

   public class RootObject
   {
       public Result result { get; set; }
       public string method { get; set; }
   }
3. Deserialize json string

   RootObject Product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
4. Loop through data

   Product.Result[i].price  **<=this is what you want**